# Transfer file from AWS S3 to Jira

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, jira-rest-api

How to transfer file from AWS S3 to Jira?

I use Node.JS AWS-SDK and library 'jira-client' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client)
This code not working:

```
const
  s3Object = AWSS3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'thisisbucket',
    Key: 'thisiskey'
  }),
  S3Stream = s3Object.createReadStream();
  jiraClient.addAttachmentOnIssue(jiraId, S3Stream)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Ok');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I got HTTP 500: Stream ended unexpectedly

Comment: addAttachmentOnIssue() is not custom right ? I am not sure we can directly attach stream to a Jira ticket.